# How to find/distinguish between success and failure in EXT JS

Tags: javascript, button, extjs, submit, handler

Hello I am trying to work around my success and failure handlers. I have a button, which removes data. But just to establish the basic connection, I am trying to submit my form. I used this code from java2s.com website.

So I have given a url where the form has to be posted and on return should display an alert, either a success or a failure. Now when I do this, my dummy page "x.php" is loading. I can see that through console and NET window in the firebug.

Do I have to echo something specific in my call back for success or failure?? How would it know if it was a success or a failure???

```
var rem = Ext.get('remData');
new Ext.Button({
        renderTo:rem,
        text:'Remove',
        handler:function(){

                var formPanel = Ext.getCmp('form1');
                formPanel.el.mask('Under Process','x-mask-loading');

                formPanel.getForm().submit({
                        url:'x.php',
                    success:function(f,a){alert('+');},
                    failure:function(f,a){alert('_');}
                    });

                }
});
```

I am unable to understand what would f,a be?? if they are function and action, are they passed through the url that I am submitting the data to??

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the documentation for the [Submit action](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.Action.Submit). It it lists what parameters the success and failure functions take. Paraphrasing from the documentation:

- `f`: The Ext.form.BasicForm that requested the action
- `a`: The action class that submitted the form. The `result` (`a.result`) property of this object may be examined to perform custom postprocessing

Comment: Ok I ran through , now when I run this page, I am getting neither of the alerts, how do I solve it?

Comment: no, there are no javascript errors. I get a 200 status code, when the file I mentioned in the url loads, which means it is a success.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Ext API Docs](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/), open Ext.form.BasicForm, and find the submit() function and check out the description.

`f` is the form that was submitted, `a` is the action.  From the docs:

```
action : The Action object which performed the operation.
The action object contains these properties of interest:
- failureType
- response
- result : interrogate for custom postprocessing
- type
```

Comment: Ok I ran through , now when I run this page, I am getting neither of the alerts, how do I solve it?